# Is it possible to create an Excel file with R?

Tags: r, excel, save, saving-data

General question: is there an R package out there that creates an Excel file? Or saves data frames as excel files? Or is it only possible to write files that already exist in a specific directory? If it is possible to create new Excel files, is there also a possibility to create multiple Excel sheets in that file?

Thank you for answering!

Comment: `library(writexl)`  : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/writexl/writexl.pdf

Comment: Or if you want to use formating and other features, package `openxlsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the package [`openxlsx`](https://ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/index.html) is the most popular package to do this.

Example:

```r
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(iris, file = "writeXLSX1.xlsx")
```

And yes, you can also add multiple sheets. See a nice introduction [here](https://ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/articles/Introduction.html).